# Suppress "Stack Exchange" in site names in network search results

Tags: feature-request, search

Stack Exchange has a new [network-wide search engine](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=good+job). It looks great, but the presence of "Stack Exchange" after site names is repetitive and redundant, given that the search is within Stack Exchange.

I recall that site names have a long form (with Stack Exchange) and a short form (without it). I suggest using the short form here.